# Получить наибольший результат из 3-ех числ, используя +, *, ()

Tags: c#

Наткнулся на интересный [сайт](https://www.codewars.com/) со всякими интересными задачами и наткнулся на такую:

Дано a,b,c и нужно не меняя их местами, используя +,*,() получить наибольший результат.

Так если было передано 1,2,3, то наибольший результат будет достигнут

```
(1 + 2) * 3 = 9
```

На ум приходит только перебрать все варианты и выбрать максимальный, так как оно конечно и их не так много.

Можно ли что-то более элегантное придумать?

Comment: На ум сразу приходит, что если выбрать наибольшее число из 3-х, то на него и следует умножать...

Comment: Кстати, посмотрел чужие решение и там, вроде, все решается перебором, что не интересно.

Comment: @Bulson Совершенно верно, но если наибольшее стоит посередине, то его складывать с наименьшим и умножать на оставшееся. В итоге задача упрощается до нахождения минимального значения либо справа, либо слева, от этого складываем прежде либо правое плечо, либо левое и результат умножаем на оставшееся число.

Comment: @ГеннадийП 

Comment: @Геннадий, если все числа меньше единицы, то умножать их невыгодно, ну или 1, 1, 1

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно достаточно элегантно оформить данную задачу. Например, вот так:

```
static (int, string) getMax(int a, int b, int c)
{
    (int, char) maxOp(int x, int y) =>
        x + y > x * y ? (x + y, '+') : (x * y, '*');

    string str;
    int tmp, res; char lop, rop;
    if (a < c)
    {
        (tmp, lop) = maxOp(a, b);
        (res, rop) = maxOp(tmp, c);
        if (lop > rop)
            str = $"({a} {lop} {b}) {rop} {c}";
        else str = $"{a} {lop} {b} {rop} {c}";
    }
    else
    {
        (tmp, rop) = maxOp(b, c);
        (res, lop) = maxOp(a, tmp);
        if (lop < rop)
            str = $"{a} {lop} ({b} {rop} {c})";
        else str = $"{a} {lop} {b} {rop} {c}";
    }

    return (res, str);
}
```

Варианты выполнения:

```
> getMax(3, 2, 0)
[(6, 3 * (2 + 0))]
> getMax(3, 2, 1)
[(9, 3 * (2 + 1))]
> getMax(1, 2, 1)
[(4, 1 + 2 + 1)]
> getMax(1, 2, 2)
[(6, (1 + 2) * 2)]
> getMax(2, 2, 2)
[(8, 2 * 2 * 2)]
> getMax(2, 2, 1)
[(6, 2 * (2 + 1))]
```

Comment: Ну это по сути тот же полный перебор

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, это перебор, но не полный. (на каждом следующем шаге отсекается половина возможных вариантов)

Comment: Поясните, почему вы сравниваете крайние операнды и начинаете расчёт с меньшей стороны. Какая под этим математика? Укажите источник такого решения. "Какие ваши доказательства", тскть.

Comment: @Deadooshka, **самый мой нелюбимый вопрос...** Я подобрал такое решение интуитивно и императивно. 1) Исходил из расчёта на то, что на максимальное число лучше умножить на промежуточный резултат, чем добавить его, поэтому предположил, что второй находимый оператор будет '*' в больше половины случаев. 2) В любом из случаев средний операнд войдёт в скобки, в т.ч. если операторы одинаковые и скобки опущены, поэтому им можно пренебречь. 3) Это обычная арифметика, если я понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: с отрицательными значениями не везде корректный результат https://dotnetfiddle.net/RTYJ90